# How to configure a Microsoft-hosted agent to build an EXE preferring 32-bit?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a Windows Service project hosted on DevOps repository and the `.csproj` file of this project has the "Prefer32Bit" option enabled, and VS already outputs an EXE that runs as 32-bit process.

However, the EXE outputted from DevOps build agent doesn't prefer 32-bit (I checked this with CorFlags.exe).

[image]

I tried adding the `OSArchitecture` build variable [as in this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops),  but it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems that you've located the issue and resolved it, you can consider adding your comment as an answer to help others! See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), just a reminder :)

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT noted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I configured `Prefer 32-bit` in the Debug (not the Release) build configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using the VSBuild task, please try modifying the `platform` to `x86`:

```
# Visual Studio build
# Build with MSBuild and set the Visual Studio version property
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    #solution: '**\*.sln' 
    #vsVersion: 'latest' # Optional. Options: latest, 16.0, 15.0, 14.0, 12.0, 11.0
    #msbuildArgs: # Optional
    #platform: # Optional
    #configuration: # Optional
    #clean: false # Optional
    #maximumCpuCount: false # Optional
    #restoreNugetPackages: false # Optional
    #msbuildArchitecture: 'x86' # Optional. Options: x86, x64
    #logProjectEvents: true # Optional
    #createLogFile: false # Optional
    #logFileVerbosity: 'normal' # Optional. Options: quiet, minimal, normal, detailed, diagnostic
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops#yaml-snippet

Comment: Thanks Aman. Actually the problem was embarrassingly simpler than this. I configured `Prefer 32-bit` in the Debug (not the Release) build configuration.